# What to use for background with ARGB

Tags: c#, colors, argb

I am struggling to understand what background I should be using as to avoid interference from whatever is in the background.

When I start tweaking the "A" of an ARGB frame that's sitting on top of another image, the background affects my results.

For example, I might choose a specific frame to have a background color of [128, 128,128, 128] but when I use the System.Drawing NET Core library to extract the ARGB value, the value depends on the background, namely if its green it shoots up the G value, etc.

I have no issue when I keep the A at 255.

What should I put behind the frame/image as to avoid interference? Or is that not possible?

Comment: I mean you could put a "known" quantity behind it, however i am not sure i understand why you are trying to do this. whats the result going to be used for? why is the alpha not 255 if you want the pure result?

Comment: The `A` in ARGB stands for "Alpha", and refers to how opaque the color is--in other words, the lower `A` is, the more the background will bleed through. This is the intentional behavior, and, in fact, the entire point. What are you expecting A to do?

Comment: @Putnam I'm trying to encode information into color and read it externally, I was hoping I could use the alpha to increase data density

Comment: Ah, in that case you usually want a fully transparent background anyway. Is this not viable?